# How do I continue to validate next element in an array for a block after a value fails in the block

Tags: ruby, arrays, validation

I am trying to validate strings in a array with in if else.

```
strings = ["Hello", "goodluck", "Bye" ]
strings.each do |i|      
  if i == "Hello"
    @browser.text.should == ("Welcome")        
  elsif i == 'goodluck'
    @browser.text.should == ("Good Bye")       
  end
 next
end
```

So here for first condition, the browser doesnot have text "welcome", so it fails. But the iteration doesnot continue to validate next element in array. Please guide me if I am going wrong anywhere? or any other ways to do where all the elements of array is tested for the block irrespective of fail.

Comment: Do you need that `next` there?

Comment: I use it or not, its not working

Comment: I tried using next bcoz if there is fail, next iteration is not happening. But it did not help. if all is good then it goes to next element in the array.

Comment: You should return `true` from the block. Otherwise block will no be called for further iterations

Comment: so i tried using true in place of next. It did not help. Where exactly I need to return true

Comment: What are you trying to do ???

Comment: Actual i am trying to do: validate each string for a format & if it matches the format, then verify for a text in the page else if string doesnot match format, then verify different text in the page. So issue is, after validating for the format, it checks for the text, if text is not present or wrong, then its not continuing to next element validation in the array.

Comment: when your `if` clause get matched, you are doing match inside it. Good understood, now why you are performing test inside `if`? when you got failed you want to move for next iteration,understood. But when success what you want to do?

Comment: might be that i'm wrong, but if you're inside a testcase, a failed assertion will stop the whole testcase (because it's failed then)

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside a testcase, (assuming you're using rspec or something similar) a failed assertion will stop the whole testcase (because it's failed then). Technically a failed assertion raises an Exception, which get's caught somewhere outside the testcase (in rspec a 'it {}') to display the reason why the test failed.

In your case it might help to split up your test in to several cases, each with one assertion, but to give better advise I'd need to know what your trying to do.